# history.pushState not working in controller

Tags: angularjs, pushstate, html5-history

I have this two buttons in my html :

```
<a href="" class="sbtn sbtn-default" ng-click="GoToNext()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Next </a>
<a href="" class="sbtn sbtn-default" ng-click="GoToPrev()"> Prev <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
```

then in my controller :

```
$scope.GoToNext = function () {
    var nextPage = getNextPage("next");

    history.pushState(null, "Site Title", nextPage);
    getQuestion();
}

$scope.GoToPrev = function () {
    var prevPage = getNextPage("prev");

    history.pushState(null, "Site Title", prevPage);
    getQuestion();
}
```

and the getNextPage function is :

```
function getNextPage(type) {

    var querystr = window.location.pathname.split('/')[4];
    var currentQuestion = querystr.split("-")[1];
    var currentBook = querystr.split("-")[0];

    switch (type) {
        case "next":
            return ((currentBook + "-") + (+currentQuestion + +1));

        case "prev":
            if (currentQuestion == 1)
                return (currentBook + "-1");

            return ((currentBook + "-") + (+currentQuestion - +1));

    }

};
```

my Url is look like this :

*http://localhost:14799/app/Dashboard/Question/1-330*

getQuestion function just get the data's from the server , I already tested it out and it return the data with no problem , actually it return the data at page load with no problem .

what I'm trying to do is changing the URL and get the next or previous question by clicking on those buttons . but what is happening is it calls the getQuestion function but the URL is not changing . if i look very closely to the URL and pay attention it get change and get back to previous page very very fast , just a flash !

I have nothing in my code to return to previous page .

what I try is add console.log in getNextPage function to see if it call twice , but it doesn't , it just call once for every click .

if I try to pushState in console , it work !

I also add console log at the end of my getQuestion function to see if its get stuck in the middle of the function , but no ! console log is happening but it return to the previous page .

I just desperately testing things , but no luck .

Comment: This is annoying to me because I'm not using ngRoute and just using Angular for a few things and want to do some manual `pushState` to no avail. I've noticed wrapping in a `setTimeout` works, but `document.location.search` still returns the old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

year a go i was struggling with this problem and now i understand it. its not how angular works. i should of used ngRoute module to provide navigations. its not about the pushstate not working or something else, its about how angular works.

i don't need `$scope.GoToNext` or `$scope.GoToPrev` for navigating because angular would do it for me automatically. just change the route and its done. everything works fine.

Answer (score -2):

`pushState` is inconsistently supported on various browser platforms. Try [`History.js`](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) instead.

Comment: as i said , it work if i try it in console , so it works and there is no problem with browser .

Comment: no bro , i change my code and i try to get it to work with ui-router (because of multiple views)